# Android 11 - Not able to open google map application with mimeType text/plain

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, manifest, android-11

Not able to open the navigation app when passing the mimetype as "text/plain"

```
 <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
```

But when I pass mimeType as "image/jpeg" or "*/*" I'm able to see navigation apps as chooser apps.

But in intent, I'm passing only Latitude and Longitude so could someone explain why mimetype as "image/*" is required here?

Android 11 also new and map concept also new to me any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can remove the `data` so your app could see all apps related to the `android.intent.action.SEND` action

Comment: @AgiMaulana : If I remove the data element.. It is not working

Answer (score 0):

What if you add explicitly the package of g-map to your manifest:

```
 <manifest package="com.example.game">
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
</queries>
...
```